# Use html in placeholder

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, icons, twitter-bootstrap, placeholder

Is it possible to use html in `placeholder` attribute? For example i want to use `<i class="icon-search"></i>` instead of  `Search` text.

```
=form_tag search_editions_path, method: :get, class: 'navbar-search pull-left' do
  =text_field_tag :q, nil, class: 'search-query', placeholder: 'Search'
```

Comment: Could you provide the HTML that you imply you're asking about? And encoded HTML characters can be used in the placeholder attribute (`&lt;` instead of `<` for example), but otherwise no: html cannot be used inside of an HTML attribute.

Comment: Sorry, it's a haml only. But it's not uncommon to see search textfields with an icon, for example. What is a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, placeholder attribute accepts only plain text, for search text inputs you can use absolute positioned elements over them and for the user it will look like it is inside the text input.